# Different layout on search page depending on category post

Tags: php, search

I would like to display different layouts for post with different categories on the search page:

I tried with this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['the_category'])) {
    $type = $_GET['the_category'];
    if($type == '1') {
?>
```

But it doesn't work, could someone can point out a solution?

Full code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="padder">
    <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_search' ); ?>
    <div class="page" id="blog-search" role="main">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      <?php bp_dtheme_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>
      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_post' ); ?>

      <?php
      if(isset($_GET['the_category'])) {
        $type = $_GET['the_category'];
        if( $type == '1' ) {
      ?>

      <div class="blog-post">
        <div class="post-title">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"
               title="Fixed link <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </div><!--post-title-->
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
          } else {
            // no thumbnail
          }
        ?>
        <div class="text">
        <?php
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        the_content( __('Read more','OneCommunity') );
        ?>
        </div><!--text-->
      </div><!--blog-post-->
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <?php    
        } elseif( $type == '4' ) {
      ?>

      //Display layout for post marked with category 4
      <?php
        }
      }
      ?>

      <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_post' ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php bp_dtheme_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
      <h2 class="center">
        <?php _e( 'No posts found. Try a different search?', 'OneCommunity' ); ?>
      </h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_search' ); ?>
  </div><!-- .padder -->
</div><!-- #content -->
<div id="sidebar">
  <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-blog')) : ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-ad-blog')) : ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div><!--sidebar ends-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you have `the_category` in URL? It isn't native WordPress query variable, how exactly are you faceting search by categories?

Comment: I don't understand your question, i want to display a different post layout in the search results based on category. I am using the standard wordpress search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if ( in_category(4) )
```

in order to add different HTML for a post in category 4. This has to be in within the loop for it to work.

Comment: <?php
        if ( in_category(4) ) ) { ?>
 // Do something
<?php } else {
 // do something else}
?>

This should be the code you are talking about? I am unable to figure out a solution. Could you please implement with more info your answer?